# How to configure HUE to be connected to remote Hive server?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I'm trying to use HUE Beeswax to connect my company's Hive database. Firstly, is it possible to use HUE installed on my mac to be connected with remote Hive server? If it does, how am I supposed to find the address for the Hive server which is running on our private server? Only thing I can do is to type 'hive' and put some sql queries in hive shell. I already installed HUE but can't figure out how to connect it to the remote Hive server. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to get the `hive-site.xml` and put it in your Hue conf folder. Also ensure the system has connectivity with the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a desktop connection to Hive, you only need a JDBC client, not a full web app like Hue.

In any case, [Hive CLI is deprecated. Beeline is preferred](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/02/migrating-from-hive-cli-to-beeline-a-primer/).  To use Beeline and Hue, [you need a HiveServer2 running](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2).

To find the address of the HiveServer2, if you have it, you  need to find your `hive-site.xml` file on the Hadoop cluster, and export it. Other ways to get this information are available in Ambari or Cloudera Manager (but if you're using a Cloudera CDH cluster, you already have Hue). The Thrift interface is what you want. Default port is 10000

When you setup the Hue, you will need to find the `hue.ini` file, in which, edit the section that starts with `[beeswax]` and fill in the necessary values. Personally, I find that section fairly straightforward

You can read the Hue github to find the requirements for running it on a Mac